# JavaScript/jQuery events not firing on elements within nested <divs>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, css

I am building a basic RSS reader app that, which the 'story' is clicked, the information for it is displayed in a modal view. The 'stories' or RSS feed items are displayed in a row that scrolls.

The problem I am having is, the elements that will respond to JS event (such as hover) stop firing at a certain point in the DOM chain of nested div elements.

In more detail:

My rails app outputs  markup that resembles this:

```
<div class="overscroll">
    <div class="feed-row" data-feedid="<%= feed.id %>"> 
        <div class="feed-item-container">
           <div class="feed-item-overlay">
            <span class="feed-item-title">
               <%= entry.title %>
            </span>
            <br />
            <span class="feed-item-published">
               <%= entry.published.strftime("Posted on %m/%d/%Y") %>
            </span>
            <span class="feed-item-url">
               <%= entry.url %>
            </span>
            <div class="feed-item-content">
               <%= entry.summary %>
            </div>
         </div>

              ... repeats ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
```

The problem now is this -

I have stored important data within `feed-item-container` element in which I want to extract using jQuery on a simple click event. The problem is, a JS click/hover events stop responding below the `feed-row` element, leaving me unable to access any individual `feed-item-container`s -

i.e. this works:

```
$('.feed-row').hover(... console.log('Works!'););
```

but this will not:

```
$('.feed-item-container').hover(... console.log('Does Not Work!');
```

Or another way:

```
- overscroll <-- .hover works
    - feed-row <-- .hover works
         - feed-item-container <-- .hover DOES NOT WORK HERE, OR WITH ANY NESTED DIVS
```

My stylesheet (using Sass) looks like this:

```
.overscroll
{
    position: relative;
    width: 98%; 
    height: 200px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    /*border: solid 1px #000;*/ 
    /*margin: 30px auto;*/
    /*float: left;*/
    /*display: block;*/

    .feed-row
    {
        width: 10000px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;

        .feed-location
        {
            display: none;
        }

        .feed-item-container
        {
            position: relative;
            height: 200px;
            width:  200px;
            background-color: #000;
            background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/200/');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            float: left;
            cursor: move;
            display: block;
            overflow: hidden;

            .feed-item-overlay
            {
                opacity: 1;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                background-color: black;
                width: 200px;
                height: 100px;
                color: white;
                font-weight: normal;
                cursor: pointer;

                .feed-item-title
                {
                    font-size: 125%;
                }

                .feed-item-published
                {               
                }

                .feed-item-url
                {
                    display: none;
                }
                .feed-item-content
                {
                    display: none;
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

And finally, the raw output taken from Firebug, with any Javascript transformations and whatnot:

```
<div class="overscroll" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; cursor: -moz-grab;">
    <div style="position: absolute; background-color: black; width: 6px; height: 200px; margin: 0px 0pt 0pt 1147px; border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; z-index: 999; opacity: 0;">
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; background-color: black; width: 132.954px; height: 6px; margin: 194px 0pt 0pt 0px; border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; z-index: 999; opacity: 0;">
    </div>
    <div data-feedid="5" class="feed-row" style="display: block;">
        <div style="background-image: url(pic.png);" class="feed-item-container">
            <div data-keyboard="true" data-backdrop="false" data-controls-modal="modal-feed-view" class="feed-item-overlay">
                <span class="feed-item-title">
                    <!-- TITLE Clipped -->
                </span>
                <br>
                <span class="feed-item-published">
                    <!-- DATE Clipped -->
                </span>
                <span class="feed-item-url">
                    <!-- URL Clipped -->
                </span>
                <div class="feed-item-content">
                    <!-- CONTENT Clipped -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Repeated RSS Items were here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

So, my question is this:

Why can't I click anything below `feed-row` in the nesting tree, and how do I approach fixing this?

Many thanks

**Edit #1**

While I was typing up my pseudo jQuery calls, I left out the class period, but they **do** exist in my actual script, just a typo on my part... apologies

Comment: The divs it's not working on, are they loaded after the page has loaded? Are the elements inside `.feed-item-container` floating?

Comment: Does feed-item-container get dynamically replaced or added after you run the jQuery to install the event handlers?  Does the feed-item-container content exist at page load when the jQuery runs to isntall event handlers?  If it doesn't exist at the beginning or gets added/replaced, then you need to use `.delegate()` or `.on()` on a persistent parent.

Comment: Both correct in content being loaded after the document, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing since this is an RSS feed, this data is loaded dynamically?  If so, consider wiring these events with jQuery's `on`

```
$(".overscroll").on("hover", ".feed-item-container", function() {
});
```

Or if you're using a jQuery version < 1.7, use `delegate`

```
$(".overscroll").delegate(".feed-item-container", "hover", function() {
});
```

Comment: Typo on my part - the class marker is in my actual script - didn't double check my pseudo-example close enough, sorry!

Comment: Seems like I'm about to get burned by AJAX and DOM updates yet again :) Yes, the inner contents are loaded dynamically - going to give this approach a shot

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you missed the "." to indicate the "class" selector. Did you mean:

```
$('.feed-row')
```

and

```
$('.feed-item-container')
```

Comment: Added edit above - this was a typo in the SO question, but marked correctly in my script